# Usage of “per”, “each” and "every"?

Tags: grammar

Can you tell me which ones are grammatically correct and why?

> Students must study *for* 20 hours *per* week.
>   Students must study *for* 20 hours *each* week.
>   Students must study *for* 20 hours *every* week.
>
> Students must study 20 hours *per* week.
>   Students must study 20 hours *each* week.
>   Students must study 20 hours *every* week.

I am also not sure is it necessary to have "for" after study.

Please help thank you.

Comment: Hello Supphanet, welcome to EL&U. Unfortunately it's not very clear what you are asking, your title asks about the difference between _per, each_ and _every_ but your question  asks which are grammatically correct. Now all six sentences are grammatically correct but can have slightly different meanings. Do you want help with those meanings? Also have you tried to research the meanings? If you have you should let us know what you have found out and what still confuses you. Good luck with your research.

Comment: Yes. Please. I want to know those meanings. I also have changed the title. Hope it is better. Thank you.

Comment: Personally, I think "for" is required, otherwise it sounds as if the students are studying the hours.

Comment: I also think that *per*, *each*, & *every* are all acceptable, but that each option conveys a stronger message that the previous one; i.e. "*every week*" is stronger that the other two - perhaps too strong.

Answer (score 2):

If you "study 20 hours" this is ambiguous: It may mean that you study an important period of history which lasted 20 hours. An example might be the moon landing or the use of the atomic bomb.

So to be clear that the period of 20 hours is the time devoted to study, rather than the time studied, the word "for" is required.

Other than that, the difference is not in the denotation, the primary meaning, but in the connotation, the additional meanings which are carried with it.

- "per" generally means an averaging. One may study for 5 hours one week, and 15 the next,  and achieve 10 hours per week.
- "each" generally means either an equal distribution, or a minimum, or both. Studying 10 hours each week would mean at least 10 hours every week.
- "every" in this case means the same as "each" but with more emphasis on the consistency, that there can be no missed weeks.

So in this case these words are almost the same. It is only the additional feeling, or connotation, which is different.

Comment: I would agree with all your points, Ben. Also you've expressed them better than I would have done. +1