# Per vs every when followed by something non singular

Tags: american-english

In a list of prices, I see:

- $1.99 per 3 days
- $49.99 per 3 months
- $1.99 per day
- $199.99 per year
- $9.99 per week

The first 2 seem awkward to me the last 3 seem fine.  If I replace `per` with `every`, they all seem "normal" and not awkward.

- $1.99 every 3 days
- $49.99 every 3 months
- $1.99 every day
- $199.99 every year
- $9.99 every week

Is there some rule that makes per need to be followed by something singular?

Comment: probably "each" is a better replacement in many or most cases. Each and every are subtly different. Bear in mind that "3 days" is a unit here and that "per 3 days" probably would need to be "each/every 3 day period" see also: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/492828/usage-of-per-each-and-every

Comment: I’d interpret “Per 3 days” as meaning if I wanted 9 days I could pay $5.97.   But $1.99 every 3 days could mean I’d have to keep making $1.99 payments as I went along.

Comment: It seems a bit unusual to me but I don't see anything wrong with the phrases with "per."

Comment: Absent context, I would assume the best version to be "$1.99 **for** 3 days / $49.99 **for**  3 months, etc.

Comment: I agree with @Jim, that's the distinction I see. "every X" is used when you sign up for a subscription that automatically renews.